# Can you cancel partition deletes in Windows 7 setup?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

In the Windows 7 setup where you choose the drive to install on you can delete partitions. I accidentally deleted a partition on the wrong drive and I wondered if it's possible to revert? I am still in the setup now and haven't restarted my computer but in the command prompt in advanced options I can no longer see the drive.

Is there anything I can do to cancel the delete and not lose the files?

**Edit:** This question is not a duplicate - it it specifically asking about the process *during setup*, i.e. is there any way back from a delete and not just another *how do I recover a partition* drive. Or maybe it's deemed too similar, then fair enough :)

Comment: The files have probably not been deleted (formatted), but the partition table may been edited to remove the partition from it. If that's the case, you may be able to recover or replace the partition table entry using a special tool.

Comment: Any "special tool"s you could recommend at all?

Comment: Testdisk is exactly the right tool for this job, but you must have another disk to recover to. once you have a clean copy, you can move the data back to the source disk. Never attempt to recover data in place. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk Be sure to exit the installer to be sure that you don't overwrite the partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using `Disk Commander` in the Microsoft DaRT [Emergency Repair Disk Commander](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee460909.aspx) I was able to ask it to scan for partitions and restore them. The scan can take a while but once it was done my partitions were back as expected perfectly.